# How to teach a rat to not litter in a different spot

Tags: toilet-training, rat

Rats are rather clever little creatures. I have potty-trained my two male rats within a single week.

Until recently, they have found a new favorite spot.

The method I used to teach them was *association of smell*. Simply move their litter to the litter-box in the corner, and soon they picked up on it.

The problem is, they now started urinating in the **other** corner. I assume this was due to one of the two accidentally doing so, and the other then assumed by association of smell that this is an OK place to do so.

**How do I teach them not to do that anymore?** I tried cleaning it profusely, but it doesn't help all that much. And I am not really sure how I can move urine, or the smell of it, to the litter box..

Comment: did you clean the spot specifically with a urine cleaner?

Comment: @Zaralynda No. I have tried various anti-bacterial cleaners though

Comment: Which kind of litter do you use? And is it different enough from their regular bedding that they're not getting confused? How far apart are their two spots that they use? Also, if possible, you should avoid using anything stronger than dish soap when cleaning cages, rats have very sensitive lungs. I know occasionally a deep clean is necessary but it shouldn't be a weekly thing if you can avoid it.

Comment: I do not use any bedding, it has a plastic base (the one rat didn't react well to pet bedding. The litter I use is a moderate to high absorption pet litter, which they seam to like.

As for the other spot, it is in the corner opposite the litter box, probably about ~80cm away.

Answer (score 3):

Don't move the urine to the litter box, move the box to the urine.

Add a second litter box in the new corner. Then basically keep doing what you are doing, cleaning it very frequently to persuade the rats that the other one is a better place to go. Using a second separate litter container makes a thorough cleaning easier, rather than just trying to clean part of the cage every time they use it. And if it isn’t effective in retraining them to the original litter box, at least the rats are still going in a litter box.